# cx_ORACLE passing parameters ORA-01008 error

Tags: python, oracle, parameter-passing, cx-oracle

I´m trying to execute this Python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import cx_Oracle
import csv

con = cx_Oracle.connect('CIRCU3/CIRCU3@localhost:1521/korcl')

params = {'year': str(2016)}
df = pd.read_sql_query(script_SQL, con, params)
```

where the script_SQL is:

```
SELECT
kwhIT AS kwhIT,
kwhCLT AS kwhCLT,
TEMPEXT AS T
FROM T_MEASURES_TE
WHERE 
ID_SITE = 21
AND TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY') = :year
```

and it returns an error ORA-01008:  Not all variables bound.

I can't figure out which is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are not being passed correctly to pandas.read_sql_query(). You need the following code instead:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(script_SQL, con, params=params)
```